# How to add iptables ip blocklists to Plesk 10.4.4 (CentOS)?

Tags: iptables, .htaccess, blacklist, ip-blocking

I'm trying to figure out the best way to add IP blocklists to my Plesk 10.4.4 server (CentOS). It's a simple Virtual Server I recently acquired through my hosting company.

I've used .htaccess files in the past to block IP address ranges; IP ranges were from [Wizcrafts.net](http://www.wizcrafts.net/nigerian-blocklist.html) for example. But that only blocks http/https access. Plesk has a decent Firewall module, but that only allows you to enter one line at a time.

I've heard of APF, but I'm afraid of trying to install it with Plesk, as there are many ports that should remain open for upgrading/managing the Plesk server. The APF route will probably get me into a mess of problems.

So, I assume that iptables are a possibility. Is there a way I can shell in and add the blocklists as iptables? Does anyone have any experience or advice? I'd like to block these Nigerian hackers and other country hackers from everything I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at fail2ban? 
[fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

It seems there has been work to use it with plesk.
[fail2ban with plesk](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Fail2ban_talk:Community_Portal#Fail2ban_on_CentOS.2FRedHat_Plesk)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the fail2ban advice. It doesn't really answer the question, but provides a nice solution to the underlining problem.

Comment: Update - Finally got away from Plesk. It's like having a tumor removed. Moved to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

http://easyfwgen.morizot.net/gen/

this is a very useful website, which generates a good iptables script, that is as far as casual servers are concerned, pretty much complete.

you have the choice of few customizations, and editing the resulting script later on is fairly straightforward.

and hey, you can always just read it all, and learn how to make your own iptables script :)

when this script is run on a VPS, it will throw few errors due to some kernel module loading in it, that can't be achieved on a VPS, you can safely ignore them.